# Is there a way to perform the "andand" technique in java?

Tags: java, ruby

As described [here](http://laktek.com/2011/11/23/basic-patterns-for-everyday-programming/):

> We connect the object and its method (or property) call with a logical
>   AND operator (&&), so the method is only invoked if the object is
>   truthy (not null). This technique is commonly known as 'andand'.

In Ruby, we're able to do this:

`name = @person && @person.name`

This way we don't have to explicitly check if `@person` is null.

Is there a similar technique in java?

Comment: Do you want to do an and operation or are you looking for a simple way to check if a property is null?

Comment: I want to check if the property is null and assign the value in a single shorthand line of code.

Comment: http://laktek.com/2011/11/23/basic-patterns-for-everyday-programming/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ternary operator` However it's not very similar to `&&` technique, but works that way only.

```
person != null ? peson.name : <default name>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a similar technique in java?

There is nothing as concise.

There was a Project Coin [proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000047.html) to add the so-called "Elvis" operator and related ones to Java 7.  However, it didn't make the cut.

Answer (score 2):

No, only when checking Strings you can achieve this by inverting the order of the comparison.

Instead of

```
if (role != null && role.equals("admin"))
```

you'd write

```
if ("admin".equals(role))
```

Answer (score 0):

Java do have [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). The problem is that Java does not assume `null` to be equivalent of `false` (and not-null - equivalent of `true`).